# Workaround for Zoom in Graph overview?

Tags: gephi

I am currently working on a medium size graph in gephi (5k nodes, 25k edges);

Whenever I click on "Center on Graph" button, the Zoom slider stops working. If the file is saved in this situation, this error stays even after reopening Gephi.

Closing this graph file and opening other file makes the Zoom starting working again.

Is there a way to fix the Zoom slider? If not, any workaround to zoom in and out without the slider? (for instance, using the script console...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some tests, I realized that an easy way to fix the problem is using the mouse wheel.

It changes the zoom level, and also fix the zoom slider.